# type error ocurs when I re-answer a "while"-loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

In my program the user is asked to submit a value for N.
This is my bit of code where I get stuck:

```
        while (N > 23 or N < 1): 
            N= input ("Choose a number between 1 and 23")
```

When I first provide an input of N between 1 and 23, the program goes to the next step like it should. And when I provide a wrong answer, like 24, the program prints "choose a number between 1 and 23". but when I THEN enter a valid input like 5, the terminal says this:

```
How high is your pyramyd? 40
Choose a number between 1 and 23 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyramyd.py", line 6, in <module>
    while (N > 23 or N < 1):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

What does this mean and how do I solve this? I want it to be a loop that asks me to submit input until I provide a valid input and then continues to the next command.

Comment: `input` returns a string.

Comment: Because in your while loop you redefined N not as a number, but as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever input you take is entered as `string`. That's what the error also specifies that you are trying to compare a `string` with `int`.

Try this :

```
while (N > 23 or N < 1): 
    N= input ("Choose a number between 1 and 23")
    N = int(N)
```

Comment: Welcome @Lara2000. Please upvote the answer if it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a string at the moment. It needs to be an integer.

```
N= int(input("Choose a number between 1 and 23"))
```